# Which PostGIS SRID is most efficient for a spatial index?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-index

I have a PostGIS-enabled database with a table called `locations` that stores latitude-longitude points (SRID 4326) in a column called `coordinates`. However, all of my lookups on that table convert the points to a metric projection (SRID 26986) mainly to do distance comparisons.

Obviously I'd like to create a spatial index on the `coordinates` column. My question is, which is the best (most *computationally* efficient) SRID to use in the `coordinates` spatial index in this case?

I can either index using SRID 4326...

```
CREATE INDEX locations_coordinates_gist 
ON locations 
USING GIST (coordinates);
```

Or using SRID 26986...

```
CREATE INDEX locations_coordinates_gist 
ON locations 
USING GIST (ST_Transform(coordinates, 26986));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered this helpful information reading the PostGIS documentation on the [`ST_Transform`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Transform.html) function...

> If using more than one transformation, it is useful to have a
>   functional index on the commonly used transformations to take
>   advantage of index usage.

So it seems the answer is, use both! I have created two indices, one with each SRID.